# Select where unix timestamp falls on specified hour or day

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to build a dynamic where for a MySQL query. The user can select how many hours or days ago they want data for. I want the data to fall on the particular hours or days ago.

Here is the code I'm using right now which does not work:

```
$condition['dates'] = 'Specific';
$condition['date_operand'] = 'Hour(s) ago';
$condition['date_value'] = '3';

if ($conditions['dates'] == 'Specific' && !empty($conditions['date_value'])) {
    if ($conditions['date_operand'] == 'Hour(s) ago') {
        $where[] = "date_format(from_unixtime(l.date_updated), '%Y-%m-%d %H') = date_format(now() - interval ".$conditions['date_value']." hour, '%Y-%m-%d %H')";
    }
    else if ($conditions['date_operand'] == 'Day(s) ago') {
        $where[] = "date_format(from_unixtime(l.date_updated), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval ".$conditions['date_value']." day, '%Y-%m-%d')";
    }
}
```

It does not seem to be working whatsoever. The `l.date_updated` is a unix timestamp. You can see what I'm trying to achieve, it just isn't working.

## UPDATE

Here is the MySQL where statement from the example which is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable l
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.date_updated), '%Y-%m-%d %H') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

It does not cause an error, it simply isn't selecting what I want.

## FINAL UPDATE

My query was actually fine. It appears my PHP code was connecting to a development database which hasn't been updated in years. That's why when I selected 3 days ago it returned zero rows.

So please, a little respect, for I am Dion, lord of the idiots.

Comment: If this is a mysql question, I'd suggest removing the PHP and just include your query. It will make it much easier for us to see what's wrong with the query if we can actually see the query.

Comment: I updated the OP.

Comment: What is the MySQL data type of the `date_updated` column? `TIMESTAMP`? `BIGINT`?  `UNSIGNED INT`? Please [edit] your question to show that information.

Comment: @O.Jones It is an `INT`, which contains a unix timestamp.

Comment: Have you checked return of `FROM_UNIXTIME(l.date_updated)` to ensure the dates are in the time zone you're expecting? You say it isn't selecting what you want, but what is it selecting? Anything?

Comment: @miken32 Even if that is the case (which is impossible because I'm using unix timestamps for everything), it would still at least select SOME data when I do it by day. I have hundreds of rows of data for each day.

Comment: When I run the query via PHPMyAdmin it works. This is hilarious. Probably PDO doing some weird type casting.

Comment: Maybe it is a PHP problem after all. If you're using PDO you should really be using parameters and not building a query with string concatenation.

Comment: That's a good point. However, even if I change `".$conditions['date_value']."` to `3` in the code it still doesn't work.

Comment: Nvm I am an idiot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you want to choose rows where your `date_updated` value lies in a range of time.  For example, I *think* you mean, if `NOW()` is `2017-04-03 17:55:22`, you want all the records timestamped between `2017-04-03 14:00:00` and `2017-04-03 14:59:59.99999` inclusive.

Here's how you do that in a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) way: a way that can use an index on your `date_updated` column.

This expression truncates `NOW()` to the top of the hour: 17:55 to 17:00:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

This backs up three hours.

```
 DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') - INTERVAL 3 HOUR
```

The beginning of your timestamp range is:

```
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') - INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
```

The end of your timestamp range, then, is

```
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') - INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

So, this `WHERE` clause does the trick.

```
 WHERE l.date_updated >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')-INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
   AND l.date_updated) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')-INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Notice the `<`, not `<=`, at the end of the time range.

There's some time zone stuff happening here. Unix timestamps are (or should be) always recorded with respect to UTC. The `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function always converts from local time to UTC, and the `NOW()` function always works in local time, so this all should work properly.  But you might investigate all this timestamp junk if you're still getting the wrong rows, or no rows.

Please notice that your time precision would be the same and your life would be easier if your column had the `TIMESTAMP` data type rather than the `INT` data type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still don't understand why my original query doesn't work, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TO_SECONDS:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds

```
... where TO_SECONDS(l.date_updated) >= TO_SECONDS(NOW()-INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
```

Comment: Again, I want this to select items on the same hour. So if someone selects 3 hours ago, it should grab the data that is 3 hours old on the hour. Seconds and minutes are irrelevant.

Comment: Well, then you should probably provide some sample data from your database